# Highcharts pie overlaps when loading data from XML

Tags: xml, highcharts

I'm trying to load pie chart dynamic from XML. The following code parse XML correctly but instead of showing one pie with multiple categories it create multiple pies overlap each other. I can see the color is changing and the overlapping when the report is created. Each pie has only one category. I guess I have a pointer problem here.

```
var series = {  data: []       };
$xmlDoc.find('row').each(function () {
   var $row = $(this);
   var dataRow = {};
   dataRow.name = $row.find('activityDesc').text();
   dataRow.y = parseFloat( $row.find('activityCount').text());

   series.data.push(dataRow);
});   

myChart.series.push(series);
myChart.title.text.push($xmlDoc.find('title').text()  );
var pie = new Highcharts.Chart(myChart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried directly observing the JSON to make sure that is of the correct format?

Then you can validate the JSON to make sure it meets the specifications required on the Highcharts demo pages.

Btw, to save some time you could also try out a script that converst `XML` to `JSON` 
I.e. using a tool like [xml2json.js](http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html)

Here is the sample data used for the PieChart on the Highcharts demo page:

```
series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   45.0],
            ['IE',       26.8],
            {
                name: 'Chrome',    
                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            },
            ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
        ]
    }]
```

Comment: The static code works perfect. The problem starts when I add dynamic data.